# Using TouchID with an identity provider like KeyCloak

Tags: ios, swift, oauth, touch-id

I have an app that logs in using an `OAuth / OIDC` service.

It uses the standard practice, render a `WKWebView`, complete auth with the provider, capture the callback url, set some tokens and dismiss the `webview`.

I would like to use `TouchID` to allow users to authenticate with `KeyCloak` quickly if possible.

I am unsure how to achieve this however as I am not storing the user passwords myself, they are captured via the `webview` and I shouldn't know about them.

Comment: You could store the token in the keychain and use biometric authentication to retrieve it; this would prevent "unauthorised" users from opening the app and using the stored token.  At some point the refresh period will expire and the user will need to manually reauthenticate using that point you can update the stored token

Comment: But refresh tokens are usually valid for about 30 mins.

Comment: @user1366265 that is not correct. Perhaps an access token is valid for that long, however I'd recommend much shorter, something like 5 minutes. Refresh tokens should be valid for much longer, they could technically even never expire. Once access is revoked the token would become invalid so a lifetime is not technically needed, although is good practice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do not know the credentials it's not going to be possible to sign in via TouchID.

TouchID requires you to have the username / password stored against your Keychain, the TouchID check itself allows you to access the Keychain, it's not directly connected to your user signing into to Keycloak.